# For each integer $2 \leq a \leq 10$, find the last four digits of $a^{1000}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each integer $2 \leq a \leq 10$, find the last four digits of $a^{1000}$.
$[$Hint: We need to calculate $a^{1000}$ mod $10000$. Use Euler’s theorem and Chinese remainder theorem.
For example, $10000 = 2^4 \cdot 5^4$; $2^{1000} \equiv 0$ mod $2^4$, and $2^{500} \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$.$]$

$\mathbf{My~Attempt:}$
$\mathbf{Case~1}$: If $a = 10$
Then, notice that $10^4 = 10000$ divides $a^{1000}$.
So, we have $a^{1000} \equiv 0 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$ if $a = 10$.
Therefore, the last four digits of $a^{1000}$ must be $0000$ if $a = 10$.
$\mathbf{Case~2}$: If $a \in \{ 3, 7, 9 \}$
Since, by the Euler's Theorem, we know that if $a, m \in \mathbb{N}$, $m > 1$ and $\text{gcd}(a, m) = 1$,
$~\hspace{82mm}$ then $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~m)$.
Then, we notice if $a \in \{ 3, 7, 9 \}$, then $\text{gcd}(a, 10000) = 1$.
So, we have $a^{\phi(10000)} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$.
Since, $\phi(10000) = \phi(2^4 \cdot 5^4) = \phi(2^4) \cdot \phi(5^4) = (2^4 - 2^3)(5^4 - 5^3) = 8 \cdot 500 = 4000$.
Then, we have $a^{4000} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$. Which means $a^{4000} = (a^{1000})^4 \equiv 1^4 = 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$.
So, we have $a^{1000} \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$ if $a \in \{ 3, 7, 9 \}$.
Therefore, the last four digits of $a^{1000}$ must be $0001$ if $a \in \{ 3, 7, 9 \}$.
$\mathbf{Case~3}$: If $a \in \{ 2, 4, 6, 8 \}$
I only know $a^{1000} \equiv 9376$ (mod $10000$) but do not know how to find it !!
$\mathbf{Case~4}$: If $a = 5$
I only know $a^{1000} \equiv 625$ (mod $10000$) but do not know how to find it !!

$\mathbf{My~Questions:}$
First, I don't think for my $\mathbf{Case~2}$ is okay to say $a^{4000} = (a^{1000})^4 \equiv 1^4 = 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$ $\implies$ $a^{1000} \implies 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$ but I don't know what else I can write to get $a^{1000} \implies 1 ~(\text{mod}~10000)$.

Also, I am totally lost in Case 3 and Case 4. I know that $a^{1000} \equiv 9376$ (mod $10000$) if $a \in \{ 2, 4, 6, 8 \}$ and $a^{1000} \equiv 625$ (mod $10000$) if $a = 5$ but I don't know how to find these results.
Well in Case 3, I use the Chinese remainder theorem and can find out that $9376 \equiv 0$ mod $2^4$ and $9376 \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$. But have no idea on how to get $a^{1000} \equiv 9376$ (mod $10000$)

Comment: The hint says use Chinese theorem but you haven't used it. For case 2 the reasoning seems flawed since $(-1)^4=1\pmod{10000} $

Comment: A bit farther on the hint: If you can find the equivalence classes of $a^{1000} \pmod{2^4}$ and $a^{1000} \pmod{5^4}$, CRT tells us this is enough to find the class of $a^{1000} \pmod{10^4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake, as @kingW3 points out, is casting aside CRT.

Plus you're forcing the issue (and making a bit of a mess).

As a hint, let's do $a=3$.  Since $10000=2^45^4$ with $(2^4,5^4)=1$, we split it up with an eye towards applying  CRT *first*, and *then* apply Euler's theorem: $3^{1000}\cong(3^8)^{125}\cong1\bmod{2^4}$ and $3^{1000}\cong(3^{500})^2\cong1\bmod{5^4}$.

Now by the constant case of CRT, we conclude $3^{1000}\cong1\bmod{10000}$.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why you can say that $3^{1000} \equiv (3^{500})^2 \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$. How do you know that $3^{500}$ is congruence to 1 ?

Comment: Euler's theorem.  $\varphi (5^4)=500$.

Comment: Okay, I got all $3^{1000} \equiv 7^{1000} \equiv 9^{1000} \equiv 1$ mod $10000$. But I still can not figue it out with why $2^{1000} \equiv 9376$ mod $10000$. Right now I can only find that $2^{1000} \equiv 9376 \equiv 0$ mod $2^4$ and $2^{500} \equiv 9376 \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$

Comment: Okay.  Here's where you need help again.  You need to learn how to apply CRT.  I like to use Bezout coefficients.  So we need $a,b$ such that $a2^4+b5^4=1$.  Then the answer will be $a2^4\bmod{10000}$.

Comment: I'm getting $ -39\cdot 16+1\cdot 625=1$.  So I get  $-624\cong{9376}\bmod{10000}$.

Comment: So the hard part was getting the Bezout coeffs.  You can practice and get good at using the extended Euclidean algorithm, or cheat and use an online calculator (like I just did).

Comment: Yeah, I know that $x \equiv 0$ mod $2^4$  and $x \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$. Then $x = 16y + 0$ which then $16y \equiv 1$ mod $5^4$, then I solve Diophantine equation $16a - 625b = 1$ so I got the $a_0 = -39$ and $b_0 = -1$. So I have $y \equiv -39 \equiv 586$ mod $5^4$ $\implies$ $x=16y \equiv 16 \cdot 586 = 9376 \equiv 0$ mod $2^4$ or $\equiv 1$ mod $5^4$. But how can I tell that $2^{1000} \equiv 9376$ mod $10^4$

Comment: A way that always works, and comes from the existence part of the proof of CRT, is that, if you can just find the Bezourt coeffs, then the answer, in this case, by CRT, is $x=1\cdot(-39)\cdot2^4+0\cdot1\cdot625=-624$.  Your last step is unnecessary.  Once you get the Bezout coeffs you are basically done.

Comment: Okay, thanks I think I got it

Comment: Great!  You just need to remember that result from the proof.  There are other ways of doing alot of these problems, that is, of doing the last step of applying CRT.